# Rename gitlab repository for pipeline Ci/CD runner

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a small problem when I run pipeline runner for self hosted gitlab repository.
Runner want clone the repo because of the address, in Advanced settings my path is something like

`http://125.161.171.87:8888/Group/Project`,

but the address for the ssh is

`git@project.com:Group/Project.git`,

so is there a chance that I change the ssh address to

`git@125.161.171.87:Group/Project`

or this is something that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to change `external_url` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`. That will change address from

`git@project.com:Group/Project.git` to `git@125.161.171.87:Group/Project`

More information here on the gitlab [forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/renaming-the-gitlab-host-url/685).